# Python - Can't find pip.ini or pip.conf in Windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, configuration, pip

I have Python 2.7.8 installed on my Windows 7 machine, which comes with pip already pre-installed.  I'm able to successfully install new packages from pip and now I need to add a custom repository URL to the install list of pip.

To do so I need to modify `pip.ini` which is in `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`, according to the [Official Manual](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#config-file).  However, there is no `pip` folder anywhere (not in `Roaming`, not in `Local`, not in `LocalLow`)
nor is there a `PyPa` folder in: `C:\ProgramData\PyPA\pip\pip.conf`

Could you tell me where I should search for `pip.ini`? How can I add a foreign repo to the install list?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new file `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`?

Comment: Why pip doesn't support a command to show this info?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Finally got it sorted.

Apparently for Windows users `pip.ini` config file is not created, however can be added manually!

just create new `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini` and content of custom repository:

```
[install]
find-links = https://<login>:<password>@your.repo.com/custom/url
```

Reference: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file

Comment: On python 3.6 it works for me from C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.conf only.

Comment: Using Python 3.8, I had to manually create the `pip` folder and the `pip.ini` file as well. I used it for our corporate proxy settings.

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire Where did you create your pip folder and how did you ensure it was picked up when launching? _pip config -v list_ lists a selection of variants.

Comment: @QHarr, I created it at the sugested place in this answer (`%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`). As for getting picked up, I prayed for it, and it worked.

Comment: @QHarr See the answer of alexandrul. You can for example check with an erroneous pip.ini that has no [install] section header. I have installed Anaconda for my user only. Then, both the 2x`user variant` and the `anaconda variant` work (error thrown). I have not checked the `global variant` since I have a user installation.

Answer (score 169):

Instead of checking a list of well-known locations, you can ask `pip` to list the valid locations:

```
pip config -v list
```

---

**Fun fact**

On the same machine, with the same pip version, the valid locations can vary based on the actual Python version.

Environment: Win 7 x64, the `HOME` environment variable is set to `D:\Home`

Python 3.7.3:

```
> pip config -v list
For variant 'global', will try loading 'C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'user', will try loading 'D:\Home\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'site', will try loading 'C:\Python37\pip.ini'
```

Python 3.8.0:

```
> pip config -v list
For variant 'global', will try loading 'C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\foobar\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini'
For variant 'site', will try loading 'C:\Python38\pip.ini'
```

Comment: Won't `pip config -v list` or `pip config --verbose list` do?

Comment: @dumbledad I don't have a Windows machine at hand, so I can't check. On Linux it works with `-v`

Comment: @dumbledad thank you, it's working fine on Windows too

Comment: This is really helpful and works across platforms, thank you.

Comment: Thank you. This worked.
Instead of copying files blindly at `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`, check which pip path a certain environment is using and create a `pip.ini` file at that location.

Comment: FYI, this command doesn't seem to work if the files don't exist -- i.e. if you don't have any of the files, this command doesn't produce any output. Instead, to see which files *would* be used (even if they don't currently exist), you can use this command instead: `pip config debug`

Comment: @Seth it's still working for me, as intended, showing the valid locations that would be checked (even if the actual files don't exist yet). The `-v` is mandatory for this purpose. Win 10 x64, Python 3.11.2

Comment: @alexandrul Weird, I don't know why it didn't work for me then (I tried both with and without the `-v` flag). I tried it on Windows 10 as well, running Python 3.9.1 and Pip 21.2.4, and got the same result (no output) regardless of which terminal I ran the command in (Git Bash, Powershell or cmd).

Comment: @alexandrul Update: After upgrading Pip from `21.2.4` to the latest version (`23.0.1`), your command (`pip config -v list`) worked as described above

Answer (score 22):

A bit late, but for reference:
Try adding the pip.ini file in `%USERPROFILE%\pip\pip.ini` (usually: `C:\Users\<username>\pip\pip.ini`).

Comment: Putting the pip folder directly in the user folder is the what worked for me on Windows 7 and Windows 10 using Python 3. Thanks for the tip, Moshe.

Answer (score 21):

It's been 7 years, and I think there's now a better answer for most people -- but it does depend on version of pip.  For the most recent pips I'm using:

```
    $ pip config -v debug
```

lists where it's looking and you can decide which location is
most useful for what you've got in mind.  It does look like a fairly recent
change: On a year-old docker image I had with pip 20.1
I got "ERROR: Need an action (edit, get, list, set, unset) to
perform."  On that system, `pip config -v list` gave a list of files it would try, this is supposed to be 'global', 'user' or 'site' variants of pip.ini locations.

For Windows 10, for pip 21.2.4 on both 3.9.6 and 3.6.8, I get response below with `pip config -v debug`, while `pip config -v list` is silent (unless a pip.ini is found).

```
global:
  C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini, exists: False
site:
  c:\py\myvenv\pip.ini, exists: False
user:
  C:\Users\myname\pip\pip.ini, exists: False
  C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini, exists: False
```

From a downloaded image I got from dockerhub in June 2021 with pip 21.2.2 and python 3.6.10:

```
 pip config -v debug
 env_var:
 env:
 global:
   /etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf, exists: False
   /etc/pip.conf, exists: True
 global.extra-index-url: http://trynexs:8081/repository/repo_group/simple
 site:
   /usr/local/pip.conf, exists: False
 user:
   /home/tanhauser/.pip/pip.conf, exists: False
   /home/tanhauser/.config/pip/pip.conf, exists: False
```

Answer (score 18):

On windows pip.exe looks for "pip.ini" in this order:

```
C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini
C:\Users\<username>\pip\pip.ini
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is still the case. On my Win7 machine with py3.6.3 when I tried adding `[list] ...format=columns` it only took effect when placed in APPDATA.

Comment: That was for 2.7, so you could be right.
I had used sysinternals procmon to watch Python.exe was doing; searching in order for access to "pip.ini".

Anyone can do the same to ensure the order is still the same:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: I can confirm part of it. I have put an erroneous pip.ini both in `C:\Users\<username>\pip\pip.ini` and in `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`. Then `pip config -v list` reported username\pip directory (I had forgotten a section header). This shows that the the username\pip directory comes before the appdata\pip directory.

Answer (score 8):

Pip [changed the location of the config file in windows starting in pip 6.0](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/f63d1e3abb3a05027f44eb97c4493bc66fe3d9e1) the [pip config docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file) explain the location of the config files as follows.

#### pip --version >= 6 (as of version 18.1 hasn't changed again yet)

```
%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini
```

#### pip --version < 6

```
%HOME%\pip\pip.ini
```

#### Inside a virtual env

```
%VIRTUAL_ENV%\pip.ini
```

#### Site-wide win7+ (same as of win10)

```
C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini
```

#### Site-wide winxp (note windows vista side wide not supported)

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\pip\pip.ini
```

#### NOTE: If multiple configuration files are found by pip then they are combined in the following order:

1. The site-wide file is read
2. The per-user file is read
3. The virtualenv-specific file is read

Also pip added a config command starting in pip 10.

```
pip config --help
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a bit late, however, this post is high on the rankings when searching. Inside a virtual environment pip.ini can also be in the root of the virtual environment. From the [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/?highlight=pip.ini#config-file%20docs) and https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/?highlight=pip.ini#configuration

```
Inside a virtualenv:

On Unix and macOS the file is $VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf
On Windows the file is: %VIRTUAL_ENV%\pip.ini
```

Answer (score 4):

All the answers are partially wrong and right.
It depends on **how** your system is configured. The only way (for me) to find out was to patch  `site-packages/pip/locations.py` at the point where `site_config_files` is assigned (around line 120 for pip 9.0.1)

> print('########## ' + str(site_config_files))

and then run `pip search foo`

On my system it printed `########## ['C:\\ProgramData\\pip\\pip.ini']`, of which location I assumed I could not create/edit. But it just worked.

Btw, for my system %APPDATA% points to `C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming`, which is **not looked at** when running `pip` on my system.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than guessing first **check** if you have any default **global/local config** which is read by **pip** with the below command:

```
pip config list
```

This will give all details of the default config loaded by python.

If the above command **doesn't give any output** please try to find where pip tries to find for the **global config** file with the below command:

```
pip config --editor <path to editor of your choice> edit
```

The above command will open the config file which pip reads by default or else it will give an error saying that the file doesn't exist.

If there's an error please go ahead and create the exact directory and file structure as show in the error. Once the file has been created please make your changes e.g.

```
[global]
cert = /path/to/base64/ssl/certificate.pem
proxy = http://username:password@ipaddress:port
```

Save the file and please try to check (the above mentioned check command) if the configs are loaded by pip or not.

For more info please follow [pip config documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_config/)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you acually have a `pip.ini` file, not `pip.ini.txt`.

Comment: Indeed, you may only notice this if you check your files in a terminal!
-> If your config was actually picked up by pip you will also get a print of the variables specified in the config file when you tpye pip config -v list after the list of preconfigured config paths, e.g.: global.index-url='%URL%'

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, python will load the config from path below. So, if ***pip.ini*** file is not exist in these paths you can create the new file by refer these path depend on environment scopes (global, user & site) that you need python execute.

- For variant 'global', will try loading 'C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini'
- For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\MyName\pip\pip.ini'
- For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini'
- For variant 'site', will try loading 'c:\python39-32\pip.ini'

By the way, you can check the paths as above by
`pip config -v list`

Answer (score 1):

For me (Windows 8, pip 9.0.1, python 3.5.3), the correct path was

```
c:\Users\<UserName>\.pypirc      <- sic!, even on windows
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10:

I had to create 'pip' directory inside

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\
```

then create pip.ini file inside that 'pip' directory:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini
```

No other location worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows 10 machine with multiple users I used this:

```
c:\users\all users\pip\pip.ini
```

Using `pip` version 22.3.1 with `python` version 3.10.4..