# How to get pip proxy to work with company certificate-chain?

Tags: python, pip, command-prompt

I am trying to get pip to work behind my work's proxy network. I have the credentials for the proxy and I have the certificate-chain files, but no matter what I do I cannot get it to stop throwing an SSL error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyinstaller/: There was a problem confirming the
ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
```

I've seen that pip.ini is supposed to exist in %APPDATA% but it isn't present, not even a pip folder exists there. Furthermore, people who were missing the file were able to create it and have it work that way. I tried this too and it did not work for me. I have even tried specifically specifying the cert in the `pip install` statement itself with `--cert` but with no luck.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

The certificates should live in `Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\cacert.pem` relative to your Python install directory. For example, if you have installed Python in `C:\Python3`, then the list of certificates is found in `C:\Python3\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\cacert.pem`. If you are using a python virtual environment, it is located within the venv.

You need to append your company certifcate to this `cacerm.pem` file. Make sure that the company certificate is base-64 encoded (sometimes also referred to as PEM format). Then you can use a text editor to concatenate the files.

Note: If you upgrade pip, your changes to `cacert.pem` will likely be lost. So, be prepared to repeat this operation after each update of pip.

Comment: I don't have a certifi folder under \\_vendor\

Comment: Hmm, I have 2.7, 3.5 and 3.7 installations on my machine. And indeed, that folder exists only for 3.7. I have never tried with older versions.

Comment: Still no dice, no certifi folder in \Python35\Lib\site-packages\

Comment: The riddle on not existing `pip.ini` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28280549/2311167). So, you could create `pip.ini` from scratch and populate with a cert path as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874741/2311167).

Comment: As I said in my post, I’ve tried this and haven’t had any luck