# SSL Certificate Error on Windows when using python pip

Tags: python, windows, pip, ssl-certificate

I am here to share an answer, not asking a question.
I had the SSL certificate issue when I installed python library or to create virtual environment.

`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/climb/`

Combining the results from several reference links, the steps to solve it should be,

- find your path C:\Users\<firstname.lastname>\AppData\Roaming
- create subfolder "pip", (if already have, use the existing one)
- In the "pip" folder created last step, create a file named "pip.ini"
- Edit content in pip.ini file. and save.

```html
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.org pypi.python.org files.pythonhosted.org
```

- Test install again.

It works for me and my other colleague in Singapore. Hope it works for you as well.

The links that I reference,

1. [where is pip.ini](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4087)
2. [trusted host setup in pip.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287824/specifying-multiple-trusted-hosts-in-pip-conf)
3. [set up file in pip.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278207/python-cant-find-pip-ini-or-pip-conf-in-windows)
4. [run pip without setup pip.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943410/pip-ssl-error-on-windows/50159539#50159539)